# debugging of a tapestry application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tapestry

I'm playing with the tapestry 5.3 framework in my local eclipse sandbox. Something is annoying me when I'm jumping into a breakpoint. I'm always getting the message that eclipse is unable to install a breakpoint due to missing line number attributes:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse breakpoint warning]

I know that tapestry is doing some magic stuff with my java class, according to the message I see that tapestry is working on an proxy object (see the class name). Actually I'm not interested in the proxy class generated by tapestry. I just would like to jump into the breakpoint of my class.  My question is how can I fix the issue with the breakpoint and hide the magic of tapestry?

I'm using Eclipse Juno with Maven Integration, Application is run by Tomcat 7, Tapestry 5.3.4 and jdk6.

Comment: I've never had a problem like the one you're showing and I've used Tapestry 5.0, 5.1, 5.3 and 5.4. It seems that something is really weird in your setup. Does your project configuration Java compiler options have the classfile generation checkboxes marked?

Comment: I had this one too for a while, but then it disappeared. I think it had to do with the JRE/JDK I used.